# how to keep a form on top of another

Tags: vb.net

Say I have 3 forms , Form A , Form B , Form C.

I want Form B to be on top of Form A

and Form C to be on top of Form B.

how do I accomplish this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Show(owner) overload to get form B on top of A.  You'll need to set the size and location in the Load event so you can be sure it is exactly the right size even after scaling.  And listen for the LocationChanged event so you can move the bottom form as well.  This works well, other than a few *interesting* minimizing effects on Win7.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var frmB = new Form2();
        frmB.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
        frmB.Load += delegate {
            frmB.Location = this.Location;
            frmB.Size = this.Size;
        };
        frmB.LocationChanged += delegate {
            this.Location = frmB.Location;
        };
        frmB.Show(this);
    }
```

Comment: Well, use text of my answer instead of the snippet.

Answer (score 2):

When you call [`ShowDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog.aspx) pass the form that you want it to be in front of as a parameter to `ShowDialog`.

Comment: Is there any other flexible method ?

Comment: @abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz, Can you explain why this doesn't work for you? Are you showing forms in a different way?

Comment: Because It says I have to set enabled = true , but my forms are already enabled